# Getting error trying to use adsense with free blogspot blog

Tags: google-adsense, blogger, google-adsense-policies, blogspot

Here is my snapshot, I am trying to add my adsense account to the blogspot blog.

[image]

Comment: The AdSense policies are huge.  There is no way that we can guess which is giving you problems without getting a lot more information about your site.   https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/48182?hl=en

Comment: here is my blog, can you check and tell me what can be that policy , i renamed it after this snapshot, https://ishan2007tech.blogspot.com/

Comment: Most likely insufficient content.   You have 6 posts but you need 50 to 100 to get approved for AdSense.

Comment: wao! 100 is quite a lot. If someone can spend time to write 100 post, he might not just waste time setting up free blogspot. Anyways thanks for your inputs. google should be more vocal about the cause of rejection